# sys.stdin.readlines() in pyinstaller

Tags: python, input, pyinstaller, multiline

Here, I want to creat a simple exe program that removes duplicated people using pyinstaller.

Since I want to get multiline of inputs, I used:

```
text = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

but even though it works well on Jupyter Notebook or Spyder, after when I create and open its exe file, it does not show anything but just black window. if I remove that line, I know that it works, but only single line input will be allowed.

Also, I've try to switch these two, so input first then `sys.stdin.readlines()`:

```
text = sys.stdin.readlines()
text = input('Type or Paste your text, and press Ctrl + Z.\n\n')
```

However, even though it allows multiline input, it only processes duplication function on the very first line of the input.

Here is my full code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
import sys


def duplication():


    text = sys.stdin.readlines()
    text = input('Type or Paste your text, and press Ctrl + Z.\n\n')
    text = re.split(", |-|  |,", text)


    text = list(filter(None, text)) # fastest

    names = set()
    remove = set()

    for n in text:

        if not n.startswith(("*", "-")):
            n = n.lstrip()
            if n in names:
                remove.add(n)
            elif n not in names:
                names.add(n)

    print(f'\n\nDuplicated person: {(sorted(remove))}\n\nTotal of {len(remove)}is/are removed, Total of {len(names)}is shown.')
    print (sorted(names))


    
    
def next_move():
    nxt = input("\n\nWhat do you want to do next?\n   1. Enter another text\n   2. exit\n\n")
    if nxt == '1':
        duplication()
        next_move()
    elif nxt == '2':
        exit()
    else:
        print('Please choose between 1 and 2.')
        next_move()
    
    
def overall():
    duplication()
    next_move()


overall()
```

Comment: Maybe removing the `input()` that is after the `sys.stdin.readlines()`?

Comment: That gives me TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

Your input handling is a little out, and you also don't appear to realise that the `readlines()` method returns a list of all the lines until the end of file.
Therefore the `input` call won't see any input - which might make it hang.

Since you don't discuss the data format I'm assuming that

- Lines beginning with `'#'` and `'-'` should be ignored, as should empty lines
- Each other line contains a single name, possibly surrounded by whitespace

Your `duplication` function should look more like this (untested):

```
def duplication():


    print('Type or Paste your text, and press Ctrl + Z.\n\n')
    text = sys.stdin.readlines()    

    names = set()
    remove = set()

    for n in text:

        n = n.strip()
        if n and n.startswith(("*", "-")):
            continue  # straight to next line
        if n in names:
            remove.add(n)
        elif n not in names:  # else: would be just as good!
            names.add(n)

    print(f'\n\nDuplicated person: {(sorted(remove))}\n\nTotal of {len(remove)}is/are removed, Total of {len(names)}is shown.')
    print (sorted(names))
```